# Как изменить цвет границ у tableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

Как изменить цвет границ у tableLayoutPanel. Нашел только свойство CellBorderStyle поставил Single, границы стали серыми, остальные свойства у CellBorderStyle посмотрел, они белые. Как изменить цвет границ с серого на черный, если никак, можете посоветовать какую-нибудь альтернативу.

Comment: укажи в метках winforms или WPF

Comment: Рисуйте границу сами в событии `CellPaint`.